# Connecting to samba server from spring boot application

Tags: java, samba

I have a spring boot app and a samba server running in a kubernetes cluster. How I can connect to this server from my app? Is there any gradle library for samba server? Explanation will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You can look into [Spring Integration](https://spring.io/projects/spring-integration) and use the SMB extension it provides

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-integration-smb</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

There's a short example [here](https://spring.io/blog/2017/01/18/spring-integration-extension-for-smb-0-5-0-is-available), but you have to be familiar with how Spring Integration works.

Comment: I read the documentation, but still have some questions. How am I going connect to samba itself? Do I need any password or login? I have a problem with accessing.

Comment: I have no idea, I have never used the Samba Client. Presumably you'll provide credentials when you create the bean for the client itself, but that's just my guess based off of other clients.

Comment: @AlexWhite - this may help. Spring - SMB Session Factory: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/smb.html#smb-session-factory